# Asp.NET Core with JSON File

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi

I am pretty new for ASP.NET Core and I would like to know how I can replace the InMemory Database with local json file as a data source.
The full code is found here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

Comment: It sounds like you need a tutorial on how to use a JSON-based data source, which is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Adrian
Can you share any resource ?